# How to Decode Base64 to TLV in PHP

Tags: php, tlv

I am building an inhouse Invoicing solution for my company. The government requires us to create QR Code fields encoded in Tag-Length-Value (TLV) format.

The TLV encoding shall be as follows:

> Tag: the tag value as mentioned above stored in one byte

> Length: the length of the byte array resulted from the UTF8 encoding of the field value. The length shall be stored in one byte.

> Value: the byte array resulting from the UTF8 encoding of the field value.

In the example they have provided this Base64 Output

```
AQkxMjM0NTY3ODkCCjEyLzEyLzIwMjADBDEwMDADAzE1MPaIn2Z2jg6VqWvWV6IrZZNzLF7xvZrWXW5xRV5yFY2xFu0ycXOiyqV0k7Wsh6b1IcE2Tfzap1AQAQVsktmsv1FFQ1MxIAAAAGKblFMh9nFRSn8tvftXqo9zRSz2VEAPITSZ3W7UDHKhUx+7yXGijLtJSZGXMOc+jpKwARzDl68GmmRd75NWdOs=
```

When I decode using

```php
$base64 = "AQkxMjM0NTY3ODkCCjEyLzEyLzIwMjADBDEwMDADAzE1MPaIn2Z2jg6VqWvWV6IrZZNzLF7xvZrWXW5xRV5yFY2xFu0ycXOiyqV0k7Wsh6b1IcE2Tfzap1AQAQVsktmsv1FFQ1MxIAAAAGKblFMh9nFRSn8tvftXqo9zRSz2VEAPITSZ3W7UDHKhUx+7yXGijLtJSZGXMOc+jpKwARzDl68GmmRd75NWdOs=";
echo base64_decode($base64);
```

The response i get is:

```
    123456789
12/12/20201000150���fv���k�W�+e�s,^��]nqE^r���2qs�ʥt������!�6M�ڧPl�٬�QECS1 b��S!�qQJ-��W��sE,�T@!4��n�r�S��q���II��0�>���×��d]�Vt�
```

Tag 1: Seller's Name

Tag 2: Vat Registration number

Tag 3: Timestamp of the invoice

Tag 4: Invoice Total

Tag 5: Tax Total

Tag 6: Hash of XML invoice

Tag 7: ECDSA Signature

Tag 8: ECDSA Public Key

Tag 9: ECDSA signature of the cryptographic stamp’s public key

What Am I doing wrong here and what is the right syntax to correct it?

Comment: As tag and length is stored as binary you cannot print it directly. You need to convert to usable data before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing it's binary data, we can echo it with `bin2hex(base64_decode($base64))`, and see this:

> 0109313233343536373839020a31322f31322f323032300304313030300303313530f6889f66768e0e95a96bd657a22b6593732c5ef1bd9ad65d6e71455e72158db116ed327173a2caa57493b5ac87a6f521c1364dfcdaa7501001056c92d9acbf514543533120000000629b945321f671514a7f2dbdfb57aa8f73452cf654400f213499dd6ed40c72a1531fbbc971a28cbb4949919730e73e8e92b0011cc397af069a645def935674eb

For easier viewing, I used the command line tools `base64 -d` and `xxd` to get this view:

```
00000000: 0109 3132 3334 3536 3738 3902 0a31 322f  ..123456789..12/
00000010: 3132 2f32 3032 3003 0431 3030 3003 0331  12/2020..1000..1
00000020: 3530 f688 9f66 768e 0e95 a96b d657 a22b  50...fv....k.W.+
00000030: 6593 732c 5ef1 bd9a d65d 6e71 455e 7215  e.s,^....]nqE^r.
00000040: 8db1 16ed 3271 73a2 caa5 7493 b5ac 87a6  ....2qs...t.....
00000050: f521 c136 4dfc daa7 5010 0105 6c92 d9ac  .!.6M...P...l...
00000060: bf51 4543 5331 2000 0000 629b 9453 21f6  .QECS1 ...b..S!.
00000070: 7151 4a7f 2dbd fb57 aa8f 7345 2cf6 5440  qQJ.-..W..sE,.T@
00000080: 0f21 3499 dd6e d40c 72a1 531f bbc9 71a2  .!4..n..r.S...q.
00000090: 8cbb 4949 9197 30e7 3e8e 92b0 011c c397  ..II..0.>.......
000000a0: af06 9a64 5def 9356 74eb                 ...d]..Vt.
```

You haven't explained what the possible "tag" values are, but I can see the start of that string has a tag of `0x01`, a length of `0x09`, and the following 9 bytes are ASCII/UTF-8 for `123456789`; it then has a tag of `0x02`, a length of `0x0a`, and the next 10 characters are ASCII/UTF-8 `12/12/2020`; and so on.

Later, there is a tag of `f6` with a length of `88`, and some binary data, but without knowing what tag `f6` means, I've no reason to suppose that's a problem - maybe it embeds an image, or a stream of compressed data.

Comment: I've updated my question for the tag values and this is a huge help Thank you!.

Comment: Is there a way to convert TLV Tag, Length, Value to an array?

Answer (score 1):

> For Decode QR Code (Zatca) in PHP

1. Read QR Code - example base64 code.
2. Decode the base64 code.
3. use preg_replace to remove unicode values from the string
4. And explode to get array

> Sample code

```
$base64 = "AQZSYWZlZXECDTEyMzQ1Njc4OVQxMjUDFDIwMjEtMDctMTJUMTQ6MjU6MDlaBAM3ODYFAjI1";

$decoded = base64_decode($base64);

//print_r($decoded)
//raw data
//\u0001\u0006Rafeeq\u0002\t123456789\u0003\u00142021-07-12T14:25:09Z\u0004\u0003786\u0005\u000225

$result_data = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', ',', $decoded);

$actula_data = explode(',,', $result_data);

print_r($actula_data);
```

> Output :

```
["","Rafeeq","123456789T125","2021-07-12T14:25:09Z","786","25"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

In the [Security Specification](https://zatca.gov.sa/ar/E-Invoicing/SystemsDevelopers/Documents/20210528_ZATCA_Electronic_Invoice_Security_Features_Implementation_Standards_vShared.pdf) it says:

> **4.2 Structure of the Cryptographic Stamp applied on the QR code**
> The below specifications of the Cryptographic Stamp required for the QR code are based Annex (2) of the Controls, Requirements, Technical Specifications and
> Procedural Rules for Implementing the Provisions of the E-Invoicing Regulation.
> The QR code Cryptographic Stamp shall be generated use the same digital certificate used for stamping the electronic invoices. Please refer to section 3 for the
> requirements applicable to the management and use of digital certificates used to apply Cryptographic Stamp on electronic invoices.
> The Cryptographic Stamp shall be applied on the entire TLV encoding of the QR code fields (from tag 1 to tag 6) then it shall be appended to the TLV structure. The
> Cryptographic Stamp consists of two fields as shown in the below table:

I assume the part of the data is a part of the Cryptographic Stamp